# How to solve cache size of large website?

Tags: cakephp, caching

I have a website which page numbers growing fast. An evarage page size is 500kb and i have around 10 000 pages,so this makes the size of the cache folder around 5 gigs currently. As the site has a potential to grow, i'm worried that the cache folder will become huge.

So my questions are:

1. Is the cached file size must be the same size as the page or there is a way to reduce it?
2. Is there a better solution for the cache whcih will not take so much space?

Answer (score 0):

Some more information regarding the platform and technology would have been very helpful.

But by the looks of it, did you consider using one of these

1. [MemCache](http://memcached.org/)
2. [Redis](http://redis.io/)

or other In-Memory caching solutions.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. As i'm not a coder i have no idea what is the difference between my current cache function and MameCache.Can you please clear this out. My site is built on CakePHP framework and when page is accessed for 1st time,the page cache is build in the /temp/cache folder.

Comment: I'd suggest you take some help from any of the PHP coders you know. I am not aware of how CakePHP internals work, but http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html should give you an idea.

At this moment I can say, that what you are trying to achieve is do-able. Just needs a bit of tinkering from someone who knows how CakePHP works.